# creating trigger mysql #1064

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, phpmyadmin

when i m trying to execute this query to create TRIGGER with Mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `befor_insert_VIN` BEFORE INSERT ON `vin_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `vin_table` WHERE `MODEL_CODE`= NEW.MODEL_CODE AND
`LOT`= NEW.LOT AND `VIN`= NEW.VIN >0 ) THEN BEGIN
DELETE FROM `vin_table` WHERE `LOT`= NEW.`LOT`;
END ;
END IF;
END ;
```

i received this response

> MySQL a répondu:
>
> ## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 5

Comment: You can't perform delete statement on same table with its own trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respone,but there is any way to execute the same query

Comment: create Stored Procedure and instead of Insert statement pass required values to that SP

Comment: please provide your insert statement. then i can help on SP

Comment: i INSERT DATA with  JAVA PERSISTANCE JPACONTROLLER.

Comment: in that case you can call SP from your java code with relevant parameters